# Purpose of deferring a closure with file.Close

Tags: go, closures, defer-keyword

While reading the source code of Go program for dealing with program memory I found this [snippet of code](https://github.com/liamg/dismember/blob/1651a38d940d20ee98d8765e8a695f67598fc961/pkg/proc/mem.go#L9):

```
f, err := p.openFile("mem")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer func() { _ = f.Close() }()
```

Notice the last line. Why it defers a closure with `_ = f.Close()` instead of just `defer f.Close()`?

My guess is satisfying the linter which hates unused return values. But what is the real reason for using closure in this case?

Comment: I don't know about linters, but as the author of the code you could use it to explicitly indicate that: *"I know this may fail but I don't care because handling that error would have little to no practical value in the context"* while a plain `defer f.Close()` may be construed by others as omission.

Comment: @mkopriva why not to use comments instead?

Comment: Comments can be an alternative, for sure, but why use them if you can communicate the meaning with code? Also if you have many such defers I would think it a bother to have to explain myself above each one, plus, if the code changes, there won't be the need to update the comments as well.

Comment: It's probably to make some linter happy which may raise some warnings about unchecked returned value.